# DBMSs’ ACIDity in POSIX or UNIX-Like OSs

Tags: database, unix, file-io, locking, posix

How can DBMSs guarantee ACIDity in UNIX-Like OSs when locks on files, which are the means of data persistence, are only advisory? How do they achieve immunity to uncooperative processes that can temper the files freely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ACID properties are guaranteed only when you access the RDBMS through its proper API. If you do something to the data behind the back of the DB engine, all bets are off.